# Lightning input type file issue in IE11

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using a `lightning-input type="file` and customizing it's look and feel.

```
<lightning-input type="file" onchange={handleFilesChange} class="fileUpload ts-attach">
</lightning-input>
```

By default, it looks like this

[image]

After adding css changes using static resource and changing label name from below `js code`:

[image]

Label name of this input type cannot be changed from html, it can only be changed either via css or js.

js file:

```
connectedCallback(){
    Promise.resolve().then(() => { 
        let fileUpload = this.template.querySelector('.fileUpload');  
        console.log(fileUpload);
        if(fileUpload){               
            const defaultStyle = document.createElement('style');
            defaultStyle.innerText = `.slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__button:after{
                                        content: 'ATTACH A FILE'; }`;
            fileUpload.appendChild(defaultStyle);
        }          
    });  
}
```

This works fine in all browsers expect IE11. In IE11, all css changes gets applied but label name via js does not work.

In IE11:

[image]

`console.log(fileUpload)` returns a proxy object in chrome where as in IE11, it returns below line

```
<lightning-input class="fileUpload ts-attach slds-form-element" c-lwcSelectRepairDevice_lwcSelectRepairDevice="" lightning-input_input-host=""></lightning-input>
```

Comment: You're aware that SF doesn't support IE11 unless you have the extended support, which ends Dec 2020?  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&type=5

Comment: @DavidCheng, yes and we do have the extended support